# Python - Tweepy - List referencing issue

Tags: python, list, tweepy

Firstly, explaining the process of this script:

1. Using a public list of all UK Labour MPs, I'm creating a list of their screen names (named: `screen_names`)
2. I am then trying to run through that list, and pull the last x tweets of those users.

My issue is - there's definitely an issue in working through the list around the `i in screen_names`... which means that in my output, I'll have incorrect screen names attributed to tweets. I cannot figure out what is going wrong, there are some unnecessary prints in the script below to try and work out where the error is arising from.

Any help really appreciated - thank you :)

```
screen_names = []

for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, slug="uk-mps-labour", owner_screen_name="tweetminster", include_entities=True).items():
    if user.screen_name not in screen_names:
        screen_names.append(f"{user.screen_name}")
print(screen_names)

for i in screen_names:
    print(f"{user.screen_name}") 
    counter = 0 
    try: 
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=i, tweet_mode="extended").items():
            if 'RT' in status.full_text:
                continue
            counter = counter + 1 
            print(f"{counter}\t{status.user.followers_count}\t{status.user.screen_name}\t{status.created_at}\t{status.id}\t{status.full_text}")            f.writerow([counter, user.screen_name, status.user.followers_count, status.full_text, status.created_at, status.favorite_count, status.retweet_count, user.id])
            if counter > 9:
                break
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        systime.sleep(60 * 5)
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_auth.CONSUMER_KEY, twitter_auth.CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(twitter_auth.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_auth.ACCESS_SECRET)
        api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
        print("tweep error avoided: tweepy.TweepError XXX1")
            continue
```

Comment: What's `user` in your second outer loop? Hint: probably not what you expected it to be.

Comment: @ForceBru as in {for user in tweepy.Cursor}? Shall I change that to i? (EDIT: just tried this, and changing it to user.screen_name, both threw up errors! no idea what to do)

Comment: No, the _second_ outer loop is `for i in screen_names`. What's `user` in this loop? Hint: it's the `user` from the first outer loop. And what's `i`? Hint: that's what you put in `screen_names`.

Comment: There is no user in the second outer loop, is there? Is the issue there's no relation between user from the first outer loop, and anything in the second? Sorry if I'm being really thick here - your help is really appreciated!!

Comment: Actually, the name `user` from the very first loop lives after the loop terminates, pointing to the last user retrieved from `tweepy.Cursor`.

Comment: That's the issue I've been seeing when I run it - so the last user to be added to the list is tpearce, when I run the script it runs through *all* members of the list attributing their tweets to tpearce, and then the next end of list, etc, etc so it causes a lot of errornous data. How do I get the loop to actually run through the list properly please? :/

Comment: It already runs fine - you should just decide what you want to output: the name of the current user (a.k.a. `i`) or the name of the last user seen (a.k.a. `user.screen_name`).

Comment: Just changed the print & print to .csv to i instead of user.screen_name and same issue arising - super confused!! Thank you for your help + running me through it like this

Comment: Do you mean that on each iteration only the last name is printed? What does `screen_names` look like, then?

Comment: screen_names would be like [daniella, ForceBru, tompearce, jeremeycorbyn, etc] for about 180 users. I want to run through that to pull the last X tweets for them all. Should I move to the chat as it keeps asking!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181431/discussion-between-daniella-and-forcebru).

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is actually a variety of for-loops. The one you were using is a `for obj in list` loop. I believe that you intended to use `for i in range(len(screen_names))`
So in this case, `print(f"{user.screen_name}")` is most likely to throw an error. So you would either want to print out `i` since that is the value in a list as a reference constructed in your loop signature, or replace `i` with `user` within your loop signature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this - {print(f"{user.screen_name}")} is not the purpose of the script, it's just a QA point to see what was going wrong! I've actually been fiddling with this and changed to { 48 for i in range(len(screen_names)):
 49     print(i) } too - but to no avail. Still very confused!